# Does <src=""> tag fetch the image from local computer or the website server?

Tags: html

I'm curious whether when you host a website with any tag that fetches from another website, does the website you create send that request? Or is that get request sent directly from your computer.

E.g. one scenario where you have one image at "theimage.com", your website with an image tag with src="theimage.com", and your computer who's sending a get request to your website.

When your computer sends the get request, my common sense tells me your computer directly downloads the image from theimage.com and the server doesn't have to download it first. However, when you use methods like new XMLHttpRequest() in the front end, do these put extra load on your website?

Comment: the browser downloads the image - html simply has a reference to its location that your browser does something with

Comment: What you're describing about your server downloading the image first is called a proxy. The URL in the `<img>` tag would point to your server, and your server would be responsible for hitting `theimage.com` and sending the response to the client.